# How xpath can search with class name of a div(s)

Tags: odoo-11

How to search for all DIVs with a specific class name via xpath
I'm currently using the following code:

```
    <template id="external_layout_boxed" inherit_id="web.external_layout_boxed">


        <xpath expr="//div[@class='header']" position="replace">
            <t>
                xxxxxx
            </t>
        </xpath>

    </template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching through all the Odoo plugins I finally found the answer :

```
<template id="external_layout_boxed" inherit_id="web.external_layout_boxed">


    <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('header')]" position="replace">
        <t>
            xxxxxx
        </t>
    </xpath>

</template>
```